# C++ - Constructors and self-referencing classes

Tags: c++, constructor, self-reference

Before I begin, I would just like to say thank you to anyone who attempts to help me. So now, to the problem at hand.

I have a Vector class, and I need to have a static object called zero which is a Vector with x = 0, y = 0, and z = 0

Here is my code (some unimportant bits removed...)

```
class Vector
{
public:
    Vector(double x, double y, double z);

    double x, y, z;

    static Vector* zero(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

I'm getting the error: "Expected parameter declarator"
The compiler I am using is Clang / LLVMM... Its the one that comes with Xcode... Again, thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the class you are declaring `Vector::zero` as a `Vector*` and then initializing with the `Vector` constructor. This won't work as the constructor does not return a `Vector*`. This can be fixed by dynamically allocating `Vector::zero` outside the class declaration:

```
class Vector
{
    ...
};

Vector* Vector::zero = new Vector(0, 0, 0);
```

Or, better yet - don't worry about pointers and dynamic memory allocation:

```
class Vector
{
    public:
        ...
        static Vector zero;
        // ^^^ No pointers
};

Vector Vector::zero(0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been tearing my hair out for hours on this one.

Comment: There is one more thing you should be aware of. Static members requires(!) definition outside the class (as it is done in both examples in answer)

Answer (score -2):

Truth be told, it might be better to hold a reference or `std::unique_ptr` based on your needs. This removes manual memory management from the picture.